# Which is the correct way yo use in business mails in below sentences

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence-construction, grammaticality, difference

We **haven’t been** offloaded any items by last Thursday. 
Or
We **didn’t** offload any items by last Thursday.

Pls share the correct grammatical sentence to use in business mails

Comment: Can you give more explanation what you want to say?

Comment: You'd need to clarify the question. "We haven't been offloaded..." implies someone else is offloading onto you. "We didn't offload" implies you're the one doing the offloading onto someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Phylyp mentions, your two sentences have different meanings. In either case, though, the correct tense (in business mails or otherwise) is the past perfect:

> We hadn't been offloaded any items by last Thursday.
>   We hadn't offloaded any items by last Thursday.

You are speaking of something that happened before a time point in the past (by last Thursday), so you have to use the past perfect.